# Multiply a vec3 by modelview matrix

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, vector-graphics

I have a 3D coordinate I want to transform by the modelVeiw matrix to get into view space in a GLSL shader. The point is defined in the shader, and is not affected by OpenGL's transformations. Is there anyway to do something like gl_ModelViewMatrix*(vec3 name)?

Comment: Normally a vertex shader does `void main(){ gl_position = glMatrix * aVertex; }` where aVertex is an attribute and glMatrix is a uniform. Both of these can be generated inside a shader. Just do it!

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen When I run the code vec3 tfLightPos = (gl_ModelViewMatrix*lightPos); I get the error 0(8) : error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mul(mat4, vec3)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  gl_ModelViewMatrix is a mat4.  You need to multiply it by a vec4 (with 1 in w).

Comment: Thank you!! I would vote this up, but I'm such a noob I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: The contents of w should be determined by the purpose of the point -- is it a regular vertex to be transformed or a normal (in which case w=0 and one could as well multiply the vec3 by the upper 3x3 matrix of MVM.)

Comment: All of our semantics have been sketchy.  I thought that "coordinate" was a synonym for "point", and couldn't mean a vector, but I just looked it up and I was wrong.  You're using "point" to mean either "point" or "vector/direction", which also isn't right.

You shouldn't technically do mat3(MVM) * normal; you should do normal * inverseOfMVM.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Applying_Matrix_Transformations#Transforming_Normal_Vectors